# Google Service Account logs

Tags: google-app-engine, service-accounts

I have a web application consuming a Google Service Account, on behalf of the users' service account is to invoke APIs. I'm looking at available options for logging activities and later filter based on users(or any other criteria available)

much appreciate thoughts on any similar previous experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to monitor API calls or other administrative actions that modify the configuration or metadata of resources you will have to use [Admin Activity audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/)
.

Please keep in mind that in order to view these logs

> you must have the *Cloud IAM role **Logging/Logs Viewer** or **Project/Viewer***

Audit logs also record [the identity of the caller](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#user-id) that performed an operation.

You may also find more useful information regarding filtering in the "*Filtering Audit Logs*" paragraph of the [Best Practices for Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/best-practices-for-working-with-google-cloud-audit-logging) documentation.

Let me know if this was helpful.